# Return count along with result set

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

I want unique count of one column along with the result set .e.g if the result set is like this

```
              ID      Name
               2       A
               2       B
               4       C
               5       D
               1       A
               1       B
```

The i want return from database as :

```
             Count  ID   Name
              4      2    A
              4      2    B
              4      4    C
              4      5    D
              4      1    A
              4      1    B
```

Where you can clearly see the 4 is the unique count if ID column.

Comment: You want unique value from the ID field to be selected as another column with all the rows?

Comment: @all . above is the result set not a table . I am getting this by joing multiple table .I need unique count of ID so that i would know how many unique values i am getting .
I am currently using another SP to only count that value .I want to drop that SP and count in the same SP.

Answer (score 1):

For both MySQL and SQL Server, you can do this in a correlated subquyery like this:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Name)
   FROM tablename) AS 'Count',
  ID,
  Name
FROM tablename;
```

[MySQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a499e/3).

[SQL Server Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c961/1).

Answer (score 1):

This will work on almost all RDBMS.

```
SELECT  b.totalCount, a.ID, a.name 
FROM    tableName a 
        CROSS JOIN 
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Name) totalCount 
         FROM tableName) b
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a499e/4)